# Center Bootstrap Navbar -- do not understand why navigation won't center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just started to learn bootstrap today and I was working with their example on this page http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

As you can see if you go to that page, the navigation is aligned to the left. I have attempted to use what I do in normal CSS, which is:

`margin-right:auto` and `margin-left:auto`

I also tried

`text-align:center`

Neither of these have worked and I have read their navigation documentation and I don't understand what I am suppose to do differently here.

Below is code from that navigation page. I have attempted to put the tags in all 4 navigation containers at once and individually:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header" >
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="height: 1px;margin: auto;text-align: center;">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Doesn't it center by default?

Comment: @ecbrodie It does not appear to from that demo link above, it aligns left. It seems like most of the examples and on the free template sites it aligns to the left by default.

Comment: I posted the answer below. None of what you've tried will work since the navigation is filled with floats and !important and such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's only two directions of the navigation in Bootstrap, left or right. To center the navbar, there's a couple of methods. This is what I do for one of them. Following this are two example links:
[image]

```
@media (min-width:768px) { 
/* centered navigation */
 .nav.navbar-nav {
     float: left;
 }
 .nav.navbar-nav {
     clear: left;
     float: left;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     position: relative;
     left: 50%;
     text-align: center;
 }
 .nav.navbar-nav > li {
     position: relative;
     right: 50%;
 }
 .nav.navbar-nav li {
    text-align: left
 }
}
```

This is a modified version of the above. I have no idea what you're doing with the logo.

### DEMO 1: http://jsbin.com/iJaJAzIM/3/

#### http://jsbin.com/iJaJAzIM/3/edit?html,css,js,output

---

### This is another approach:

```
@media (min-width:768px) { 
 .navbar > .container {
    text-align: center;
 }
 .navbar-header {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
 }
 .navbar-brand {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
 }
 .navbar .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: none;
 }
 .navbar .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
 }
 .navbar .navbar-nav > li li {
    text-align: left
 }
 /*add id of centerednav on the collapse or it won't work*/
 .collapse.navbar-collapse#centerednav {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block!important;
    width: auto;
    clear: none;
 }
}
```

### DEMO 2:[image] http://jsbin.com/iJaJAzIM/6/

#### http://jsbin.com/iJaJAzIM/6/edit

Comment: Good approach. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Ravimallya: I have another one here, it's for another configuration: http://jsbin.com/iJaJAzIM/6/edit

Comment: On the first it was done before for other work and the second took only a few min since I am familiar with the LESS files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the `navbar-nav` center, then you have to play a bit. Add the following style to it:

```
.navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    left: -135px; /* the width of the .navbar-brand class in negative px */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that whenever I have trouble aligning an element exactly where I want it with bootstrap, add a position:relative and left:x%; or right:x%; and get it right to where you want it.

An example:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="position:relative; left:{add-a-small-number-and-adjust-until-you-get-it-where-you-want-it}%;">
```